# Delphi: Custom hints for Tree View

Tags: delphi, treeview, hint

Is there a fast way to create 5 custom hints for 5 SubItems of Item of Tree View?

I have TreeView, 1 Item and 5 SubItems. I need a special hint for each SubItem (for first one - "F1", second one -"F2" and so on).

I can not apply this to my purpose: http://delphi.about.com/od/vclusing/a/treenode_hint.htm?

Comment: Can you provide some more details? The code that you tried would be good.

Comment: Please be more specific about what it is about that code that doesn't work for you. We aren't keen to guess all day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you just want the [`OnHint`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TTreeView.OnHint) event:

```
procedure TMyForm.TreeView1Hint(Sender: TObject; const Node: TTreeNode; var Hint: string);
begin
  Hint := Node.Text;
end;
```

Sometimes this method can be a bit crude and offer up a `Node` that you aren't obviously hovering over.  If you want more control you can use `GetNodeAt` and `GetHitTestInfoAt`:

```
procedure TMyForm.TreeView1Hint(Sender: TObject; const Node: TTreeNode; var Hint: string);
var
  P: TPoint;
  MyNode: TTreeNode;
  HitTestInfo: THitTests;
begin
  P := TreeView1.ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos);
  MyNode := TreeView1.GetNodeAt(P.X, P.Y);
  HitTestInfo := TreeView1.GetHitTestInfoAt(P.X, P.Y) ;
  if htOnItem in HitTestInfo then begin
    Hint := MyNode.Text;
  end else begin
    Hint := '';
  end;
end;
```

The definition of `THitTests` is as follows:

```
type
  THitTest = (htAbove, htBelow, htNowhere, htOnItem, htOnButton, htOnIcon,
    htOnIndent, htOnLabel, htOnRight, htOnStateIcon, htToLeft, htToRight);
  THitTests = set of THitTest;
```

As you can see this gives you a lot of fine grained control over when and what you show as a hint.

Comment: `TTreeView` has no `OnHint` event.

Comment: Maybe you are thinking about the `TListView.OnInfoTip`?

Comment: @Andreas I just ran this code with [`TTreeView.OnHint`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TTreeView.OnHint) on Delphi 2010. I'm sure it's there.

Comment: @David: Then it must have been added in Delphi 2010, because it isn't there in Delphi 2009.

Comment: Excellent!!! And can you explain me how to show different hints for different SubItems (SubItem[1]-'AAA'/SubItem[2]-'BBB')?+hint must be below a pointer (how to use htBelow)? I will be very thankful!

Comment: this code already shows different hints for different nodes. Just read the information you need out of the node.

Comment: I changed to htOnRight/htToRight - nothing happend.  "Hint:= Node.Text" - what about different text (not their text, my new text) for different SubItems (Level=2) except Item (Level=1)?

Comment: @maxfax Assign whatever text you want to `Hint`. You'll have to work out what text you want to put in there. If it depends on the node, as you say it does, then use `MyNode` in your code's logic.

Comment: @David - I'm on D2009 too, just waiting for the new 64-bit compiler and (as usually) for the whole package of previous versions. So I'm abstaining of voting here (I would prefer VirtualTreeView anyway) :)

Comment: @David Heffernan, how to make an interval before showing, I do need instant ToolTip, it is annoying.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: better to also check if GetNodeAt() returns nil, in case the code gets copied for other purposes, such as OnClick, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would set the hint of the component in response to `OnMouseMove` (or that other event that gives you mouse coordinates, from which you can get the item the mouse is over - I might have mistaken the name and at the moment I have no Delphi with me).

Comment: Yes, precisely. I believe this is the fastest and somewhat *standard* way.